# How to check if more than one option is selected upon Submit?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I have a select box with some generic options, and I want to test if the user selects more than 1 option.. but I can't quite seem to grasp how I would do so..

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Favorite Color:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <select multiple="" class="form-control" name="colors[]">
      <option>Red</option>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option>Green</option>
      <option>Yellow</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check the length of the colors array you'll get when the form is submitted.

Comment: print_r($_POST) will help you find the structure of the posted data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your form element is something like `<form action="process.php" method="post">`, you can access the number of items selected by creating `process.php` with the following:

```
<?php

    echo count($_POST['colors']);
```